# Understanding the Convolution and smoothing

Tags: sobolev-spaces

[image]

here my question is what is mean by $f^{\epsilon}:=\eta_{\epsilon}*f$ in $U_{\epsilon}$

and how can we change form $U$ to $B(0,\epsilon)$

in the molification definition and what is use convolution in sobolev spaces

and how can we prove that $\int \eta(x)\,dx = 1$

is that convulutions is well defined

Answer (score 1):

(1) The sign $:=$ means *definition*.

(2) In the left integral $f(y)$ only makes sense for $y\in U$. In the right integral, $\eta_\epsilon(y) = 0$ when $y\not\in B(0,\epsilon)$. For the equality see [Proving commutativity of convolution $(f \ast g)(x) = (g \ast f)(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/proving-commutativity-of-convolution-f-ast-gx-g-ast-fx).

(3) What means "in the molification definition and what is use convolution in sobolev spaces"?

(4) We *choose* the constant $C$ for making $\int_{\Bbb R^n}\eta = 1$.

(5) As $f$ is locally integrable and $\eta_\epsilon$ has compact support the integrand (product of...) is integrable (in both integrals).

Comment: Yes where we use convulation

Comment: ..how can we say that $\eta _{\epsilon }\in C^{\inffinty}$

Comment: @InverseProblem, see https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~loftin/ra1fal10/mollifier.pdf.